# How to run to if statements simultaneously in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing an employee login system that calculates the total time employee was logged in including the break times etc so I have two components 1. which keeps calculating the time until the employee is logged in 2. which calculates the total time of break. So in this situtation I do not want the login time to stop when the break is punched instead I want that break and login time should be running together

```
const [isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(true)
const [isBreakPunched, setBreakPunch] = useState(true)
const [breakTime, setBreakTime] = useState(0);
const [loginTime, setLoginTime] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setLoginTime(onlineTime + 1);
      }, 1000);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    } 
    if (isBreakPunched){
      const interval = setInterval(() =>{
        setBreakTime(auxTime +1);
      },1000);
      return ()=> clearInterval(interval);
    }
  });
```

When this runs, the `loginTime` is only running because the first condition is for login time indeed so to run the `breakTime` I have to stop the `loginTime`. This code is treating both as *if..else..* loop

My query is that I want to run these both simultaneously when condition is `true` of anyone, they should be independent from each other

Comment: you can put the if statement in the interval and call it only once

Comment: You could have two functions that each set an interval and return the `clearInterval` function then have the main function return an array containing the two functions that will clear the intervals...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setInterval( () => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
        setLoginTime(onlineTime + 1);
    }
    if (isBreakPunched) {
        setBreakTime(auxTime +1);
    }
}, 1000);
```

This interval checks if someone is logged in to set the login time, and sets the break time if they are on a break. BTW, it doesn't make sense that you want the login times and break times to be set depending on each other's condition while being 'independent' of each other.